# Use Angular in javascript call function parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display google maps in my page for every place (lieux).In my HTML page I have the function for the google maps.

```
<script> 
  function initialize(long,lat) {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(long, lat),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
   document.getElementById('map_canvas').style.display='block'; 
</script>
```

And I have the button to dispaly the map.

```
 <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_b" ng-controller="LieuController as lieu">
       <div  class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="lieu in lieu.lieux ">
  <button onclick="initialize({{lieu.x}},{{lieu.y}})">Click me</button> 
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
 </div>
```

So is it possible to call the function with the parameters like I did or is there another way?

Comment: can you change the inner `lieu` var name to something else. it might conflict with the controller as `lieu`

Comment: Why don't you create a directive for your map instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. Technically it's possible to mix Angular and pure javascript DOM 0 events like you are trying. However..

**1**. If you already tried your own code, then you should have seen the error Angular throws in this case:

> Interpolations for HTML DOM event attributes are disallowed.

This effectively prevents usage Angular scope data with out-of Angular world code. There is a workaround though you can take. You can render necessary data in some attributes and then use them. For example:

```
<button onclick="initialize(this.getAttribute('data-x'), this.getAttribute('data-y'))" 
        data-x="{{l.x}}" data-y="{{l.y}}">Click me</button>
```

**2**. Event if you fix above problem you will still have to address duplicated ids issue. Since your `initialize` function is supposed to render a map in separate containers per `ngRepeat` row, each with id `map_canvas`. And at the same time you library onload event, which calls `initialize` again.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

**3**. That being said, you should not build an app with such an unsuccessful design. You should really work on understanding main AngularJS concepts and philosophy.

In your case you should probably make use of `ng-click` instead of `onclick`, define `initialize` in some sort of custom service, maybe write custom directive to handle each separate map rendering in proper containers.